# Express 4.x routing and capturing URL parameters

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I'm currently refactoring my Node.js application's routing code, and was thinking of using the *Router* object introduced in *Express 4.x*. The router needs to capture some parameters in the URL, some of which happen at the very beginning.

At the moment it looks somewhat like this:

```
var views = require(...); // callback methods for generating each view.
var regexp = ':paramName(...)'; // Regular expression capturing a parameter.

app.get('/' + regexp + '/view_name', views.viewName);
```

This implementation works as expected, and in the *views.viewName* method I can retrieve the captured parameter through *request.params.paramName*.

Now, let's imagine that every valid URL needs to have that form (capturing that parameter). I was thinking of using the *Router* object like this:

```
var views = require(...);
var regexp = ':paramName(...)';
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/view_name', views.viewName);

app.use('/' + regexp, router);
```

This solution (as written) successfully routes the requests towards the *views.viewName* method, but it seems it fails to capture *paramName* in the request.

Is there something I'm missing in any of those calls so parameters captured in *app.use(...)* can be passed on to the request?

Comment: Your code snippet looks wrong, you aren't even using that `router` object anywhere in your example. You add a router as its own handler, and then never use the router anywhere.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I slipped with copy-paste. It's corrected now.

Comment: That's that I figured. That other question should be what you need.